# Django Tests Printing instead of Returning Results

Tags: django, testing

I'm suddenly running into an issue where docstring tests like this:

```
"""

>>> g = 5

>>> g

5

"""
```

Would run and look like this:

```
...
Installing Index for ModeName

....

5...

Failed example:

 g

Expected:

5

Got nothing
```

In short, it's printing out the expected results instead of returning them!  What would cause something like this?  I've been digging for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to show the expected result when running tests through Django, like the following:

```
"""
>>> g = 5

>>> g == 5
True
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It eventually started working again though I'm not 100% sure why.  I think there was an IO issue with setting the stdio

import sys
sys.stdout = sys.**stdout**
sys.stderr = sys.**stderr**